# Get height of a table row in libreoffice writer after rendering

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Is it possible to measure the height of a table row in LibreOffice writer? I want to be able to measure the actual height of a table row in the document. I create the document by copying a template file and modifying the document.xml.

**Use Case:** Need fixed height for the table. If the table height is smaller than the required height, add an empty row to make up for the height.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

LibreOffice API doesn't provide a direct call to get the height of a TextTable.

See [this thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=85738) to get an idea of how you can compute a height value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wasn't aware of cursors. Will give it a try!